# Remove duplicated row from datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, duplicates

I want unique rows. The loop should check all rows in the datagridview and see if it matches with the text from textbox, if not, it will add the value from the textbox to the datagridview. 
My problem: only the first row works, the loop only iterate through the first row in the datagridview, why wont it continue through the other rows?

```html
private void laggtill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            bool dublett = false;           
            foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {                              
                if(r.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == txtNamn.Text)  // txtnamn is a textbox
                {
                    dublett = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("Varan finns redan, gör om!");                    
                }
                break;
            }
            if(dublett == false)
            {
                DataRow dr;
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Namn"] = txtNamn.Text;
                dr["Pris"] = txtPris.Text;
                dr["Varunummer"] = txtVNr.Text;
                dr["Saldo"] = txtSaldo.Text;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
                clearRow();
                spara();                
            }
            txtNamn.Text = "";
            txtPris.Text = "";
            txtSaldo.Text = "";
            txtVNr.Text = "";            
        }
```

Comment: break; outside  if, you need to put inside

Comment: Ya, because the `break` is outside of the if block, no matter what it finds in the first row, it breaks out of the foreach loop.  If you move the `break` inside the `if` then it will only jump out the first time it finds a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(r.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == txtNamn.Text)  // txtnamn is a textbox
{
    dublett = true;
    MessageBox.Show("Varan finns redan, gör om!");    
    break;                
}
```

Move the break; inside the if.

Comment: when i do that i get  'System.NullReferenceException'  : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on if(r.Cells[0].Value.Equals(txtNamn.Text))

. sorry for the bad information, im new to this

Comment: @norrman debug and tell us what is null.
is it r.Cells? r.Cells[0]? r.Cells[0].Value?  txtNamn?

Comment: You probably need to check if r.Cells[0] is null.  if(r.Cells[0] != null && r.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == txtNamn.Text).  Something like that.